# Regex Negative Lookbehind, match a word as long as is not precede by other word

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to create a simple regex where I need to capture all the **Dogs** occurrences as long as it is not preceded by another word **Cats**. Here are some examples to test the regex:

1. My Dogs are happy -> Should Match (preceded by "My" which is valid)
2. Dogs are humans best friend  -> Should match (first word, which is not preceded by anything)
3. This is invalid Cats Dogs -> Should NOT match (preceded by a invalid word Cats)
4. The Dogs and Cats and Dogs and Dogs -> Should match (Found multiple "Dogs" and none is immediately preceded by "Cats")
5. The TomCats Dogs are valid -> Should match (TomCats is a word itself different than Cats)

I'm trying with a regex similar to this:

```
((?<!\bCats\b)\s*\bDogs\b)
```

Which doesn't give the right results (it matches all cases when it should not match the 3rd case)

Also, if I use something similar:

```
((?<!\bCats\b)\s+\bDogs\b)
```

It returns the right result for cases 1 and 3, but it does Not match case 2 since **Dogs** was found at the beginning and it is not preceded by white space.

Case sensitivity is not a problem here.
I'm using **Java** to test this regex

Comment: For clarification, please edit to add `"4. The dogs and cats and dogs and dogs -> ???"`. Also, what language or regex engine are you using? It makes a difference because, for example, a few support variable-length lookbehinds (which might be used here), but most do not. Some do not even support lookarounds of any kind.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for your reply, this will only work for a single white space and not for other white space characters such as \r, \n, \t
I'd prefer including al possible white characters.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, thanks for your reply. I have updated the question.

Comment: @LuisMiguel - `(?<![cC]ats\s)[dD]ogs` can you try this. I tested this.

Comment: @LuisMiguel: What is your language platform?

Comment: Two "dogs" are preceded by "cats" in that string. You need to clarify your first sentence to something like `'...immediately preceded by "cats", with exactly one intervening space between the two words'`. You also need to clarify whether `tomcats dogs` and `Cats Dogs` (case indifference) are matches, and whether you want all matches of `"dogs"` (not immediately preceded by `"cats "`) in the string returned when there is more than one. You no longer need #4 but one or two more examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements clearly then you may use this regex with a negative lookahead instead of lookbehind:

```
^(?!.*\bCats\s+Dogs\b).*?\bDogs\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxQwe1/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*\bCats\s+Dogs\b)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we find word `Cats` followed by 1+ whitespace followed by word `Dogs` anywhere
- `.*?\bDogs\b`: Match word `Dogs` after 0 or more characters

Comment: Note that this does not match the first ”Dogs” in ”Dogs Cats Dogs”.

Comment: Yes that was my intent (as per my understanding). If OP wants to match first `Dogs` then regex can be tweaked but it would be good to know regex platform in use.

Comment: Near won't be good enough unless you ask Siri to help.

Comment: @CarySwoveland lol :) on a second thought I will wait for OP's clarification if intent is to discard full line if `Cats` comes before `Dogs` anywhere or not.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I came up with this: https://regex101.com/r/AxQwe1/2 but will wait before I edit answer.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close to the solution. I think this regex should work:

```
(?<!Cats)\s+Dogs|^.{0,4}Dogs
```

Comment: `|^.{0,4}Dogs` seems superfluous. Why not just `(?<!\bCats )+Dogs\b`? Note that this matches ‘”Dogs”‘, but also the spaces that precede it. If there's always one space, `(?<!\bCats )Dogs\b` avoids that.